# yumでinstallオプションと同時にreinstallオプションを使えるか

Tags: php, yum

あるサーバの`yum`のリポジトリを変えたくなくて試験サーバでRPMをダウンロードすることを思いつきました。
`yum`の`downloadonly`でダウンロードしようとしたのですが、試験サーバでは幾つかのモジュールが既にインストールされていて`reinstall`を必要としていました。

```
パッケージ php-5.6.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 はインストール済みか最新バージョンです
パッケージ php-cli-5.6.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 はインストール済みか最新バージョンです
パッケージ php-common-5.6.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 はインストール済みか最新バージョンです
パッケージ php-gd-5.6.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 はインストール済みか最新バージョンです
パッケージ php-mbstring-5.6.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 はインストール済みか最新バージョンです
パッケージ php-mysqlnd-5.6.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 はインストール済みか最新バージョンです
パッケージ php-pdo-5.6.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 はインストール済みか最新バージョンです
パッケージ php-soap-5.6.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 はインストール済みか最新バージョンです
パッケージ php-tidy-5.6.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 はインストール済みか最新バージョンです
パッケージ php-xml-5.6.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 はインストール済みか最新バージョンです
パッケージ php-5.6.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 はインストール済みか最新バージョンです
```

`reintall`でダウンロードした後に`install`を実行したので全部ダウンロードできたのですが、
ふと、下記のように両方指定出来ないものかと考えました。

```
yum install reinstall --setopt=protected_multilib=false --skip-broken --downloadonly --downloaddir=. --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 php php-bcmath php-cli php-common php-dba php-devel php-embedded php-enchant php-fpm php-gd php-imap php-intl php-ldap php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-mysqlnd php-odbc php-pdo php-pear php-pecl-apc php-pecl-apc-devel php-pecl-memcache php-pgsql php-process php-pspell php-recode php-snmp php-soap php-tidy php-xml php-xmlrpc php-zts > yum_module_download.log
```

上記を走らせて見ると`reinstall`というモジュールを探しにいってしまうのですが、両方指定できる方法はないのでしょうか？

Comment: 「yumのリポジトリを変えたくない」とは具体的にどのような事を指していますか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yum`コマンドの`install`または`reinstall`オプションは同時に指定することはできません。

---

本来やりたい事はrpmパッケージのダウンロードかと思われるので、もしそうであれば`yumdownloader`コマンドを試してみてください。
`yumdownloader`は`yum-utils`パッケージに含まれるコマンドなので、確認の上インストールしておきます。

```
$ yum install yum-utils -y
$ which yumdownloader
/usr/bin/yumdownloader
```

基本的にはパッケージ名を指定して実行するだけでカレントディレクトリにrpmパッケージをダウンロードすることができますが、他にも`--destdir DIR`で保存先の指定、`--resolve`で依存パッケージも合わせてダウンロードさせることができます。
パッケージ名はワイルドカードでも指定できるので、今回の例であれば以下のように実行するとよいでしょう。

```
$ yumdownloader --destdir /tmp --resolve php*
```

Comment: ワイルドカードの指定は存じております。余計なPHPモジュールは入れたくないので本当に必要としているものだけ指定しています。`yumdownloader`と`downloadonly`で後者を選択しましたが、前者も調べてみたいと思います。